# Forking Github into AzureDevops

Tags: github, azure-devops

I'm wanting to fork a github repo into AzureDevOps, whilst retaining the capability within AzureDevOps to keep pulling changes from github as-per forking a repo within github.

Is this feasible / on a roadmap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm wanting to fork a github repo into AzureDevOps, whilst retaining the capability within AzureDevOps to keep pulling changes from github as-per forking a repo within github.

I am afraid there is no such out of box function of the "Fork" in GitHub for Azure Devops. But you can import repository from GitHub directly.

In Azure DevOps the project you want to clone the repository or create a new team project, click code tab. Click repository menu in Code Tab (it is on the top left side) and select Import repository:

[image]

Then, slect the SourceType `GIT` and add your github repository URL:

[image]

However, according to [the ticket](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/1607) on the github:

> Currently there is no Azure DevOps' build in support for automatically
>   updating your GitHub repo fork in Azure Repos.

We need do the sync manually on the dev machine.

Besides, there is an old document about [How-To Fork Git Repositories on Visual Studio Online](http://www.woodcp.com/2014/01/how-to-fork-git-repositories-on-visual-studio-online/), but we still need to create a middleman to moderate changes from GitHub before pushing them into a VSTS project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the write up.